# How can I redirect pages in Astro?

Tags: astrojs

I have a presentation on redirects
How can I do this redirect in Astro?

I am using ssr on Astro adapter and node

For example, my presentation is as follows

```
    [
           {
              "id": 1,
              "source": "/blog/category/keyword/",
              "destination": "/article/category/keyword/",
              "permanent": true
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "source": "/features/pro/",
              "destination": "/features/",
              "permanent": true
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "source": "/blog/what-is-keyword/",
              "destination": "/article/what-is-keyword/",
              "permanent": true
            },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Astro has a built-in config](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/#redirects) attribute for redirects since `astro@2.9.0` that can be set on the project's `astro.config.mjs`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';

export default defineConfig({
  redirects: {
    '/old-page': '/new-page'
  }
});
```

Considering the example of redirects you presented, the redirects object would look something like below:

```
  redirects: {
    '/blog/category/keyword/': '/article/category/keyword/',
    '/features/pro/': '/features/',
    '/blog/what-is-keyword/': '/article/what-is-keyword/',
  }
```

If you have a big list declaring many redirect statements in the format you showed, you can loop it through and build the redirects object:

```
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";

//Your original list object:
const redirectList = [
{
    id: 1,
    source: "/blog/category/keyword/",
    destination: "/article/category/keyword/",
    permanent: true,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    source: "/features/pro/",
    destination: "/features/",
    permanent: true,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    source: "/blog/what-is-keyword/",
    destination: "/article/what-is-keyword/",
    permanent: true,
  },
];

const redirects = {};

redirectList.forEach(({ source, destination }) => {
  redirects[source] = destination;
});

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  redirects: redirects,
});
```

I just tested in a latest version project (4.0.6) I have and it worked fine. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use
middleware to do that for you

by passing this array and checking if the source, then you can redirect to the destination, but in astro you should have this destination available in the pages directory, if they aren't added the same way, you can load it after the middleware

this sample will help you

```
export const onRequest = async (context, next) => {
    const url = new URL(context.url);
    const path = url.pathname
    
    routes.forEach(route=>{
       // your logic to find the matched route 
       return redirect('/destination', 302);
    })

    return next();
};
```

if they aren't exist in the pages directory and need to load them

just you have to load them in the code and return a Response with this page and it will be returned

Answer (score -1):

You can create and [API route](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/endpoints/) and use [`redirect()`](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/endpoints/#redirects) inside of it

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to use the html anchor tag . (as mentioned in [Astro doc](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/routing/#navigating-between-pages))

> Astro uses standard HTML  elements to navigate between routes.
> There is no framework-specific  component provided.